# Format interview transcript

Tags: tables, overleaf, displaystyle

I have the following format from an interview transcript :

```
Bob: 00:00:07.000 –> 00:00:17.000 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum bibendum orci quis faucibus. 
 
Alice: 00:00:17.000 –> 00:00:30.000 Nam sodales pharetra lorem, sit amet gravida justo vehicula non. Etiam eleifend mauris arcu. Sed lacinia augue id sollicitudin consequat.
```

How can I style it like this:

```
Bob:                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
00:00:07 –> 00:00:17    Morbi fermentum bibendum orci quis faucibus.
Alice:                  Nam sodales pharetra lorem, sit amet gravida justo vehicula non. 
00:00:17 –> 00:00:30    Morbi fermentum bibendum orci quis faucibus.Etiam eleifend mauris 
                        arcu. Sed lacinia augue id sollicitudin consequat.
```

PS. I tried making a table, but couldnt fit the time under the name and align it with the text on the right. Probably due to lack of experience. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Description

**Variant 1** is more LaTeX-like syntax using `{...}` for the 4 parameters: `\statement` within `interview` environment.

```
\statement{<name>}{<from>}{<to>}{<text>}
```

**Variant 2** interprets the raw input: `\firststatementx` and `\statementx` within `interview` environment.

```
\statementx <name>: <from> -> <to> <text>
```

- Note that variant 2 uses the "not recommened" argument type `u` of package `xparse` (see [`xparse` manual](https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf), 1.8 "Backwards Compatibility").

As I mentioned in the comment, it would be also possible to search and replace the raw text with some regex or write a little script that does the conversion.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % left-aligned with width as parameter

\newenvironment{interview}{%
    \begin{tabular}{L{45mm} L{80mm}}
}{
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\statement}[4]{%
    % #1 = name, #2 = time from, #3 = time to, #4 = text
    \textbf{#1:}\newline
    #2 $\rightarrow$ #3
    & #4\\[6mm]
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\firststatementx}{ u{: } u{ –> }  u{ } }{%
    % #1 = name, #2 = time from, #3 = time to
    \textbf{#1:}\newline
    #2 $\rightarrow$ #3
    &
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\statementx}{ u{: } u{ –> }  u{ } }{%
    % #1 = name, #2 = time from, #3 = time to
    \\[6mm]
    \textbf{#1:}\newline
    #2 $\rightarrow$ #3
    &
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Variant 1:}
\medskip

\begin{interview}
\statement{Bob}{00:00:07.000}{00:00:17.000}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum bibendum orci quis faucibus.}
\statement{Alice}{00:00:17.000}{00:00:30.000}{Nam sodales pharetra lorem, sit amet gravida justo vehicula non. Etiam eleifend mauris arcu. Sed lacinia augue id sollicitudin consequat.}
\end{interview}

\textbf{Variant 2:}
\medskip

\begin{interview}
\firststatementx Bob: 00:00:07.000 –> 00:00:17.000 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum bibendum orci quis faucibus. 
\statementx Alice: 00:00:17.000 –> 00:00:30.000 Nam sodales pharetra lorem, sit amet gravida justo vehicula non. Etiam eleifend mauris arcu. Sed lacinia augue id sollicitudin consequat.
\end{interview}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: That looks great and it also works for the report class! Thanks.

Though, because I have around 400 lines per person, is there any way to simplify it based on the pattern of the transcript? So I could mention the name at the beginning of the statement and then the time and words will be picked up so I wouldn't need to put the data in each bracket.

Comment: I think it's better, for better readability, tu put a '\\' at the end of each statement.

Comment: @DemiDimitrova You could search and replace it with some regex or write a little script that does the conversion. Defining it directly like that in LaTeX might be a bit complicated.

Comment: @DemiDimitrova I found a way and added it to my answer as variant 2.

Comment: @Raffaele Santoro I implemented your suggestion and added some vertical space.